# Simplest way to monitor and log the internet traffic of a ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, networking, network-monitoring

I'd like to know if there is a simple program for ubuntu server (preferably 12.04), without too much configuration, which will allow me to check what processes are using internet bandwidth, how much and log them.

For windows, something similar is a firewall like comodo, where I can see at a given time how many incoming and outgoing connections there are and how much they are using. Is there something similar for ubuntu server?

The ideal solution would be also to log them. I've tried nagios, it seems like it can do it but I spent one day reading about and it seems like it needs too much configuration. Is there something simple or maybe a specific tutorial for nagios?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For logging: [TCP Dump](http://www.tcpdump.org/)

For Monitoring: [Iftop](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/iftop/)

For ~0 Setup / configuration:

`iptables -A INPUT -j LOG; tail -F /var/log/messages` Will show all inbound packets

`netstat -punta` Will show all active / listening connections and any programs associated with them.

`ifconfig -a` generally has packet counts. (My understanding is that ifconfig is on its way out... slowly.. Don't know the netstat / iproute2 alternatives off the top of my head.)

Answer (score 2):

[nethogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/) doesn't do any logging, but for monitoring it will show you network usage by process, instead of by interface like iftop.